# When installing Windows 8, I didn't have a chance to create the default account or set up any settings

Tags: windows-8, installation

I tried to install Windows 8 on a computer. I had some problems, so these are the steps I ended up taking:

1. Install Windows 8 over Windows 7
2. I got confused and installed Windows 8 again xP
3. When the OS was starting, it never got to the login screen - it would just sit at a blank blue screen after loading
4. I used the installation disc to repair the OS

Now Windows 8 is working correctly, but I'm bothered because I never saw any screens during the installation process that let me set up the default account or prepare any other settings. When the log-in screen appears, I don't know what information to put in to log in.

So here are the questions I have:

1. Am I supposed to see any screens asking me to configure Windows before installation is completely finished?
2. Is there a default username and password I can use to log into my machine or some way to connect to an on-line account that will give me administrator access over my machine to set up a local account?
3. Would it be worth re-installing Windows 8 one more time to make sure I see the configuration options?

EDIT: I just finished talking to Microsoft support about the issue. The technician told me this:

> I see, this issue is normally related to Sony and Dell computers, basically the Video Driver is not available on the PC, so I recommend you to contact them, in order to get the instructions to access the PC and install the Drivers !

I have a Sony Vaio, so now I'm off to talk to Sony...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computer I installed Windows 8 on is a Sony Vaio VPCF122FX. According to Sony's website, [the computer doesn't support Windows 8](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/os8upgrade.pl?&mdl=VPCF122FXB). I'm going to try installing Windows 8 one more time and see if I can't "force" it to work, and if that doesn't help, I'll go back to Windows 7.

EDIT: After reinstalling Windows 8 one more time, everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Can you boot into the new O/S? Or even safe mode and see what accounts are there? It may be that it’s using the same NT accounts from the previous O/S and bypassing it, especially if it’s checking the TPM.

Comment: I am able to boot into Windows 8, but when I tried my old Windows 7 username and password, it didn't work. Thank you, though!

Comment: Is there a list of accounts in compmgmt or displayed with command [net user]?

Comment: That didn't seem to work, either. I couldn't get to a command line in the OS, so I used a command line from the installation disk's "repair OS" options. The command said that it had an error executing.

Comment: Okay I’d try run the sfc /scannow command and see if it replaces the files, your O/S doesn’t look to have installed correctly.